# Flask send_file: how do I know if I need "as_attachment"?

Tags: http, flask, content-disposition

Flask has a method to return a file: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_file

There is a parameter called `as_attachment` with a default of False, and there is a handwaavy statement about it: "For extra security you probably want to send certain files as attachment (HTML for instance)"

How do I know if my use case is "those certain files"? Or alternatively stated, what does this do as opposed to leaving this as False?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll find a clue in the same documentation, further down in the parameter list:

> `as_attachment` – set to `True` if you want to send this file with a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header.

So when the flag is set, an extra header is added to the response, which controls how the browser will handle the response. From the [MDN documenation on `Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition):

> In a regular HTTP response, the `Content-Disposition` response header is a header indicating if the content is expected to be displayed *inline* in the browser, that is, as a Web page or as part of a Web page, or as an *attachment*, that is downloaded and saved locally.

Without an explicit `Content-Disposition` header, a `text/html` response from your Flask server will be shown as a web page in the browser. If you needed the file to be saved to disk instead (the browser prompting you what to do with the file), then you need to have a `Content-Disposition: attachment` set.

So when your response content type is likely to be shown in the browser as a web page but you want the user to download it instead, use `as_attachment=True`. These days, in addition to HTML, you probably want to set that flag for images, PDF files, and XML as well.

Comment: when you say "these days" in the last part, don't modern browsers try to render all types of content, like images and PDF? Based on your response, wouldn't you want this to be False these days?

Comment: @Tommy: That depends. Do you *want* that file to be renderable in the browser? When you have a 'download as PDF' link somewhere, do you want the user to download that PDF, or do you want them to view the document in the browser?

Comment: @Tommy: when you want them to download the PDF, use `as_attachment=True`. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: @Tommy: it affects all HTTP clients that care about that header. Browsers are just HTTP clients with a HTML and JS rendering front-end, but they are not the only HTTP clients that might alter behaviour if `Content-Disposition: attachment` is set on a response. It's really just up to the client what they want to do with that header.